# Global hook for WH_GETMESSAGE hooks only to one application (VisualStudio)

Tags: c#, c++, hook, setwindowshookex

I have a C# application that calls an external DLL file for the hook process.
The hook process simply 'hijacks' key presses, converting lowercase characters into uppercase. I thought it was working only to find out that only `VisualStudio` gets hooked successfully. Other applications like `chrome` and `explorer` does not seem to perform the hook process. Is there anything I missed from creating global hooks?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

`dllmain.cpp` file:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HHOOK hkKey = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstHookDll = NULL;  //our global variable to store the instance of our DLL
#pragma data_seg() //end of our data segment

#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")    

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK procCharMsg(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
//this is the hook procedure
{       
    MSG* msg;
    char charCode;
    if (nCode >= 0 && nCode == HC_ACTION)

    {           
        msg = (MSG*)lParam;
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)                
        {
            charCode = msg->wParam;
            if (IsCharLower(charCode))
                //we check if the character pressed is a small letter
            {
                //if so, make it to capital letter
                charCode -= 32;
                msg->wParam = (WPARAM)charCode;
                //overwrite the msg structure's wparam 
                //with our new value. 
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    //passing this message to target application
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetHook()
 {
     if (hkKey == NULL)
         hkKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, procCharMsg, hInstHookDll, 0); // initialize global hook
 }

 //remove the hook
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall RemoveHook()
 {
     if (hkKey != NULL)
         UnhookWindowsHookEx(hkKey);
     hkKey = NULL;
 }

 INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {
     switch (Reason)
     {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         //we initialize our variable with the value that is passed to us
         hInstHookDll = (HINSTANCE)hDLL;             
         break;
     case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         RemoveHook();
         break;
     default:
         break;          
     }    

     return TRUE;    
 }
```

main app function that calls the hook from dll file:

```
IntPtr hInstance = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr hProc = IntPtr.Zero;    
private delegate void HookSetting();

public void SetHook()
        {
            hInstance = LoadLibrary("Dll1");

            if (IntPtr.Zero == hInstance)
            {
                // null check
            }
            hProc = GetProcAddress(hInstance, "_SetHook@0");
            if(IntPtr.Zero == hProc)
            {
                // null check
            }
            HookSetting hookset = (HookSetting)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hProc, typeof(HookSetting));
            hookset();                
        }
```

Comment: The big difference is that VS is a 32-bit process, Chrome and Explorer are 64-bit processes and require a 64-bit DLL and injector.  Try c:\windows\syswow64\notepad.exe to compare, another 32-bit process.

Comment: I have tried `notepad.exe`, and it did not seem to get the hook. What I tried are some apps within `Program Files (x84)` like Adobe Reader and the hook worked. The verdict seems to lie on the 64/32-bit difference. It is weird though, some apps within that folder like chrome and notepad did not get the hook.